# 1С Бухгалтерия 3.0 синхронизация товаров с сайтом?

Tags: 1с, синхронизация

Есть 1С Предприятие (Бухгалтерия 3.0) и требуется синхронизировать товары и заказы с OpenCart, вернее, это будет односторонняя синхронизация `opencart -> 1С`.

Загрузку заказов реализовал, все хорошо, но вот можно ли в бухгалтерию загрузить товары с сайта? В ней вообще это возможно сделать или все же без УТ не обойтись?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть множество способов это сделать:

1. Используйте HTTP-, или SOAP- сервисы и отправляйте изменения с opencart в 1С при каждом добавлении/изменении товара (изменение конфигурации).
2. Сделайте регламентное задание и отдавайте с opencart список товаров в виде json/xml по расписанию (можно реализовать в виде обработки).
3. (самый корректный на мой взгляд способ) подключитесь к бд opencart в режиме Read-Only и сделайте view с товарами. Следует учитывать, что при использовании odbc - недоступен механизм RLS .

Comment: Немного конкретизирую вопрос.

Comment: У меня уже есть список товаров, который отдает openCart в xml, другое дело, как мне 1Ской их забрать?) Если в "Управление торговлей" есть отдельно функ-нал для синхронизации товаров и заказов, то в Бухгалтерии такой функ-ал только для заказов. Все делаю по протоколу обмена CommerceML 2.

Comment: Написать свою обработку, которая выполняет три задачи:

1. Отправляет HTTP в opencart (https://infostart.ru/public/619416/).
2. Парсит XML из ответа (ЧтениеXML.УстановитьСтроку).
3. Создает и сохраняет объекты из данных XML (тут нужно писать план обмена).

Comment: Спасибо я понял.